# Autocomplete and open new window

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

**Goal**: User enters one item in text box that has autofill, after clicking button they are taken to a second page that has other corresponding items already filled out in form.

**Problem**: Autofill works but becomes erased/wiped out when second page opens (in other words the form is blank.

**Question**: I suspect I am not properly associating the actions of "form auto fill" and "open second page" with the one button. Any ideas?

```
$("#nextbutton").click(function () {
    $("#favorite_appetizer").trigger("meals");
    window.location.href = 'dinner-ideas.html';
});
```

Comment: Instead of opening the other page, do you want to load its contents onto the current page?

Comment: No, I would like to open the second page.

Answer (score 1):

Well probably problem is already solved, but try adding $_GET into javascript href, like:

```
window.location.href = '/index.php?first=1&second=2';
```

Part in part after you declare variable names and values that you can catch in second php page, like:

```
$_GET['first'];
$_GET['second'];
```

Ofcourse you need to get values from form elements with `.val()` or `.text()` and etc.
And ofcourse this has drawbacks, best used for numbers and words but not texts with symbols. Knowing more about type of form content would help, like if its data to be saved to database, you could AJAX half filled form, then retrieve its data from database with a query. If you are just filtering data, you can URL `$_GET` database ids of form elements, then query in second page by those ids. So again, depends on data in your forms that you want to pass to second page.